# How to stop adf pagination

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to stop adf pagination if next page url is not and http response is 200. Only data is null.How to check if data is null then stop pagination.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When the next page URL is there and data HTTP response is also 200 (OK), there is no direct way in Azure data factory to stop the pagination. For better understanding, you can check this [Pagination support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) document.

You can check this similar thread on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/143798/pagination-issue-in-azure-data-factory.html) and try the solution provided by MSFT engineer by setting up a new pagination rule.